# Split Delimited strings and insert them into table columns SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with one column comma delimited like:

```
     Col1  Col2
 Row1    1    1,2,3,4
 Row2    2    5,6,7,8
```

I would like to split the rows by inserting the records into additional columns in @table and have:

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  Col5
Row1    1      1    2    3    4
Row2    2      5    6    7    8
```

Please assist.

Comment: Will it always be 4 parts?

Comment: No, it will not always be 4 parts, that can vary

Comment: The data comes from an import file, the first row will have the titles eg A,B,C,D,E and they can be between 3 - 40 of them. The no. of titles always matches the no. of expected columns. So I need to first count the titles, create temp table with titles, then split the delimited records into columns and insert into table.

Comment: While I agree this is a duplicate I would avoid most of the answers provided. Looping to split strings is a bad approach. [Here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) are many better solutions.